# Simple DropdownButton not working on new page route flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

My app is simple.

I have a home page, where you press a button to open a new MaterialPageRoute.

In this new page route, I have a basic dropdown.

The problem is, that when I tap the dropdown, I get this error:

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called when widget tree was locked.
This Navigator widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is locked.
```

The dropdown is a member of "FilterPage" class. The error only happens when I put FilterPage in the new page route. If I use a new FilterPage() as home, for example, everything works perfectly.

All the code to replicate this is below. Thank you for giving this a look!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Map<String,String> categoryLookup = {
  "business":"Accounting/Business",
  "science":"Science",
  "technology":"Technology"
};

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Link',
      home: new Home(),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/filter': (BuildContext context) => new FilterPage(),
      },
    );
  }

}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  createState() => new HomeState();
}

class HomeState extends State<Home> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Browse Jobs'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/filter'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text("Home"),
      ),
    );
  }

}

class FilterPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GlobalKey<MyDropDownState> categoryKey = new GlobalKey<MyDropDownState>();
    final MyDropDown categoryDropdown = new MyDropDown(key: categoryKey, itemMap: categoryLookup);

    print("key: "+ categoryKey.toString());

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar : new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Filter Jobs'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.refresh),
            onPressed: () {
              print('Will reset dropdown using key');
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            categoryDropdown,
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDropDown extends StatefulWidget {

  MyDropDown({
    Key key,
    this.itemMap
  }) : super(key:key);

  final Map<String, String> itemMap;

  @override
  MyDropDownState createState() => new MyDropDownState();

}

class MyDropDownState extends State<MyDropDown> {

  String _selection;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new DropdownButton(
      value: _selection,
      items: getDropItems(widget.itemMap),
      onChanged: (s) {
        setState(() {
          _selection = s;
        });
      },
      hint: new Text('None'),
    );
  }

  List<DropdownMenuItem> getDropItems(Map<String, String> itemMap){
    final List<DropdownMenuItem> itemList = [];
    itemMap.forEach(
        (key,value){
          itemList.add(new DropdownMenuItem<String>(value: key, child: new Text(value)));
        }
    );
    return itemList;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem, change

```
class FilterPage extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final GlobalKey<MyDropDownState> categoryKey = new .......
final MyDropDown categoryDropdown = new MyDropDown(key: categoryKey,.....
```

to

```
static final GlobalKey<MyDropDownState> categoryKey = new .....
final MyDropDown categoryDropdown = new MyDropDown(key: categoryKey,......

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

That is, pull out the varaible declarations outside the build method and make *categoryKey* as "static" (add static because only static members can be accessed in initializers)

The error has occurred because you have declared the variables "*categoryKey*" and "*categoryDropdown*" in the build method. This creates a problem when the routing is done to the *FilterPage* and the build method gets called thus creating different instances of the *categoryKey*.

The same can be seen with the printing you have done in

*"print("key: "+ categoryKey.toString());"*

Before the change:

```
key: [LabeledGlobalKey<MyDropDownState>#4ef43]
key: [LabeledGlobalKey<MyDropDownState>#61c88]
key: [LabeledGlobalKey<MyDropDownState>#4eb6e]
```

After the change:

```
key: [LabeledGlobalKey<MyDropDownState>#ac21e]
key: [LabeledGlobalKey<MyDropDownState>#ac21e]
key: [LabeledGlobalKey<MyDropDownState>#ac21e]
```

As you see here, the category key gets the same code after the change.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're a genius! Thank you for your help, and for the great explanation.

Comment: Thanks :) Glad I could help!